# Launch windows sound recorder app

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

I want to start the default windows sound record in a Winforms app (c++/cli).In "Run" dialog, the command for Vista/7 is "soundrecorder". So I began with the easiest way:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("soundrecorder");
```

but it throws a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (Message: The System Cannot Find the File Specified). So I used the real path:

```
String^ path = Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::System);
path = System::IO::Path::Combine(path, "soundrecorder.exe");
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start(path);
```

Same result. Hard-coding full path fail too. Any other command like "mspaint" runs correctly.

I thought that the problem was in my environment/current user/machine. Then I write a stupid program in C#:

```
public abstract class StupidProgram{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Process.Start("soundrecorder");
  }
}
```

It works, and even more: If I run "StupidProgram.exe" from my app, it works too.

The application is coded in C++/CLI as 32-bits program. I'm working in Windows 7 64bits. I tested the app in a Windows 7 32bits and it works, so it seams a 32/64 bits compatibility issue.

Do you have any idea about this behaviour?

Comment: This exception has a message and an error code. Maybe you could see what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Seems to me is a path issue, c# has become more intelligent though and compiler works well for c# written code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting your C++/CLI code:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("soundrecord");
```

Quoting your C# code:

```
Process.Start("soundrecorder");
                          ^^
```

Specifying "soundrecord" doesn't work, because it's called "soundrecord **er**"

Without the exact exception text, I think specifying the full path doesn't work because your application is being compiled as x86, and you're running 64-bit Windows, and the OS is doing filesystem redirection.

I recommend you use the equivalent to your C# command: Windows has the functionality to search the path for the executable, let it do so. Hard-coding the full path will give compatibility issues in the future, when MS decides to move it.

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("soundrecorder");
                                                ^^
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, David. The problem was a 32/64 bits OS redirection. I found a [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/cfdf4474-266b-4ef5-8992-7fbdc3147521/) that has a brief explanation about redirections in 64bits OSs and a workaround. I improved my question for future uses.